# What will be the name of SharedPreference created in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sharedpreference

I just new in flutter and coming from android,
In android we declare sharedPreference name like

```
SharedPreferences sp = Activity.this.getSharedPreferences("USER", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

by this in android USER.xml file was created,

So, what will be the name of sharedPreference in created by flutter app in this example?
how i store collection of data in sharedPreference,like
USER,
HOBBIES
TYPES,
etc

```
addIntToSF() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setInt('intValue', 123);
}
```

read data

```
getIntValuesSF() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //Return int
  int intValue = prefs.getInt('intValue');
  return intValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/shared_preferences/shared_preferences/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/sharedpreferences/MethodCallHandlerImpl.java) of the `shared_preferences` package:

```java
// Line 37
private static final String SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME = "FlutterSharedPreferences";

// ...

// Line 54
preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

So the name is simply "FlutterSharedPreferences".

If you want to group entries by a model (e.g. User, HobbieType), you can add a prefix to each key:

```dart
addIntToSF() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  
  // Entries related to users
  prefs.setInt('User_intValue', 123);
  prefs.setString('User_strValue', "123");
  prefs.setBool('User_boolValue', true);
  
  // Entries related to hobbie types
  prefs.setInt('HobbieType_intValue', 456);
  prefs.setString('HobbieType_strValue', "456");
  prefs.setBool('HobbieType_boolValue', false);
}
```